# Simple PHP Error

Tags: php

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['username', 'bio', 'service', 'age'];
if (empty($text )) {
echo "You forgot to fill in a field.";
}
else
echo "Passed.";
?>
```

I know this seems like a really simple question but I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Thank you a bunch if you guys can figure this out for me.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in /home/burtonmo/public_html/v2/add.php on line 2
```

Comment: It's not valid syntax. You can't access multiple array items like that. Check [**list()**](http://us1.php.net/list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only access one element at a time in an array. Change your code to something like

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$bio = $_POST['bio'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
if (empty($username) || empty($bio) || empty($service) || empty($age)) {
echo "You forgot to fill in a field.";
}
else
echo "Passed.";
```

Comment: How would this detect if a field was left empty?

Comment: Understand the code, before posting. How will concatenating the entries pass the validation?

Comment: I don't know how the fields will be validated. I answered a question regarding PHP syntax.

Comment: Thanks, works. I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I updated the code anyway since my first example was misleading.

Comment: With this answer your get undefined index notices for POST keys that aren't set, why not directly check the var instead of setting other vars to check.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to check variables are set, the way your doing is syntactically incorrect hence the error:

Here is a dynamic way that you can loop through an array of expected keys and check the corresponding `$_POST[*]`. Good for some situations and not for others:

```
$form_keys = array('username','bio','service','age');
$errors = array();

//check is POST
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //loop $form_keys array
    foreach ($form_keys as $form_key){
        //check the corresponding $_POST[*] - if empty fill error
        if(empty($_POST[$form_key])){
            $errors[$form_key] = '*required field';
        }
    }
    //error should be empty if all went well
    if(empty($errors)){
        //good - do something
    }else{
        //bad - show errors
        //$errors contained which fields were empty
    }
}
```

Or you can do it the standard way which is the best way IMO as you can assign different errors can validate based on other types like `is_numeric()`. Though its obviously a longer piece of code.

```
$errors = array();
//check is POST
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //check user
    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $errors['username'] = '*required field';
    }
    //bio
    if(empty($_POST['bio'])){
        $errors['bio'] = '*required field';
    }
    //service
    if(empty($_POST['service'])){
        $errors['service'] = '*required field';
    }
    //age
    if(empty($_POST['age'])){
        $errors['age'] = '*required field';
    }

    //error should be empty if all went well
    if(empty($errors)){
        //good - do something
    }else{
        //bad - show errors
        //$errors contained which fields were empty
    }
}
```

Good Luck Hope it helps...